# Building recursive modules in a single reactor

Tags: java, maven

Given some maven module structure like this:

```
            a1
        A   a2
            a3
parent
            b1
        B   b2
            b3
```

There is a root module `parent`, declaring `A` and `B` as submodules. Each of the submodules has three other submodules.

If I do `mvn clean package -f parent/A` it will build A and all its submodules.

However if `a1` depends on `b1` it will not be able to resolve that dependency.

If I do `mvn clean package -f parent -am -pl A/a1` it will build `a1` and also its dependency `b1`.

Question: How do I build all submodules of `A` while resolving dependencies properly?

I would expect something like `mvn clean package -f parent -am -pl A` but this literally only builds A and none of its submodules.

Do I really have to specify all submodules explicitly or is there a way to simply build all submodules like in the first example?

Comment: After you `mvn install` module B, then you should be able build module A

Comment: Of course I could simply build everything with `mvn clean package -f parent` but I don`t want to build the whole package B. Maven should only build those few dependencies it needs for package A.

Comment: Maven expects that dependencies *it isn't building during this run* are available in a repository, either local or remote.

Comment: No, it will first look in the reactor. Only if there is no match in the reactor it will look at local/remote repositories. - In question above is, how to build everything in the reactor without manually installing dependencies first.

Comment: If you go into parent it should work to do there a simple `mvn clean package` if this does not work your dependencies between the modules (within the reactor) are wrong. Such multi module build must work without `mvn install`. If you need it it's indicator for doing something wrong. But without the whole structure and all pom's it's hard to guess what's wrong.

Comment: `mvn clean package` in parent works fine, but builds *every* single module, not only the ones *needed* by `A`. `mvn clean package -am -pl A/a1,A/a2,A/a3` is doing exactly the right thing, but this requires to specify all submodules of A explicitly. I was hoping for a way to specify "this module and all its submodules".

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. I want to recursively build a list of submodules from inside a project building script. My current workaround is to have my script temporarily add each module of the submodule as a dependency to the pom of the submodule.

If I wanted to build all the projects from a and resolve their dependencies, I'd add the following to my pom:

```
<dependencies>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>stackoverflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>a1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>stackoverflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>a2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>stackoverflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>a3</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
  </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Then I'd execute

```
mvn install -pl A -am
```

This works, but is definitely an ugly hack. I'd love an option to specify a list of modules to build, something like

```
mvn install -ml(module-list) A
```

that I could run from the command console.